# Fixing dial tcp problems

Tags: localhost, tcp, dial-up

I have installed OpenServer. I had used it for sometime before this error message began to appear:

> dial tcp: lookup test.trackstar.loc on 127.0.0.1:53: no such host.

I can't find any information about how to fix this issue. Please, help me, how  can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Was having same issue, you need to turn of VPN/Proxy extension on your browser.

Comment: correct answer. I was facing this issue because of zenmate VPN google chrome extension. The issue was resolved once I turned it off.